# Optimize EC2 -> S3 performance/cost

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

According to the EC2 documentation, its more cost-effective to use the internal address to communicate between EC2 instances.  What is the optimal way to communicate between EC2 and S3?  Is there a notion of an "internal address" for S3 and is it any faster/more cost effective than fetching from public address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/:

> There is no Data Transfer charge
>   between Amazon EC2 and other Amazon
>   Web Services within the same region
>   (i.e. between Amazon EC2 US West and
>   Amazon S3 in US West)

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/:

> There is no Data Transfer charge for
>   data transferred between Amazon EC2
>   and Amazon S3 within the same Region
>   or for data transferred between the
>   Amazon EC2 Northern Virginia Region
>   and the Amazon S3 US Standard Region.

so there is no need for a separate internal address.

Comment: When you get bigger ec2 instances the s3 file comes in faster, the data transfer rate seems to be limited to the max your ec2 box supports.

Comment: @TomAndersen how big is a 'bigger ec2 instance'? Is there a threshold?