# Upload direct to S3 or via EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I would like to build a web service for an iPhone app. As for file uploads, I'm wondering what the standard procedure and most cost-effective solution is. As far as I can see, there are two possibilities:

1. Client > S3: I upload a file from the iPhone to S3 directly (with the [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/))
2. Client > EC2 > S3: I upload a file to my server (EC2 running Django) and then the server uploads the file to S3 (as detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335649/image-upload-iphone-client-django-s3))

I'm not planning on modifying the file in any way. I only need to tell the database to add an entry. So if I were to upload a file Client > S3, I'd need to connect to the server anyways in order to do the database entry.

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651752/optimize-ec2-s3-performance-cost) as if EC2 > S3 doesn't cost anything as long as the two are in the same region.

I'd be interested to hear what the advantages and disadvantages are before I start implementing file uploads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would definitely do it through S3 for scalability reasons.  True, data between S3 and EC2 is fast and cheap, but uploads are long running, not like normal web requests. Therefore you may saturate the NIC on your EC2 instance.

Rather, return a GUID to the client, upload to S3 with the key set to the GUID and Content-Type set appropriately. Then call a web service/Ajax endpoint to create a DB record with the GUID key after the upload completes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I understand you correctly, there is no real advantage of doing this via the EC2. Would you not say that it feels a bit convoluted to (1) have a GUID returned to the client, (2) do the upload client > S3, and (3) connect to EC2 to do the data base entry. Also, I'd need to check before step one if the image can actually be uploaded, so step 0 would be to connect to EC2 and check if the file already exists.

Comment: Yes its a bit of added complexity but I'd say from the point of view of future-proofing your app and ensuring scalability its essential.  You'd be using EC2 as a proxy to S3 otherwise.  S3 is an infinitely scalable storage service - why put a bottleneck in front of it?

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify: If I upload directly to S3, I won't have the problem of uploading suff in chunks and don't need to worry about the memory of my EC2 instance, right? It's a bit like S3 is another instance, only that it is a big hard drive, which does nothing else than store stuff and accept uploads, right? So I it would indeed be unwise to go through an EC2 instance and waste my EC2 resources for uploading stuff while it could do other things (e.g. database management etc.).

Comment: Yep and not just that, the EC2 instance would be doing twice the work.... receiving the data from the client AND sending it to S3, twice the work twice the bandwidth!

Comment: i just came across exactly the same problem but im wondering about security, wouldnt it be easy for anyone to just upload/retrieve stuff it it doesnt go through a gateway? im thinking that a hacker could get the key from the app to the s3 storage (even if its just a limited one) and upload/retrieve all he wants, perhaps the retrieve can be halted with expiration based retrieve urls but what about uploading? Thanks (kinda really lost on this subject)

Comment: The secret key is never sent to Amazon - they already have it, remember, its there when you go into your keys management section in the Mgt tools.  Its not a password that gets sent to the server.  Rather, it is used to digitally sign the request on the client, and the signature is attached to the request headers. On the receiving end, Amazon also uses your private key to digitally sign the request.  If the two signatures match, they were generated with the same private key, and therefore must have originated from the user, therefore Amazon accepts the request. If they don't match it fails.